# Capping off old weatherhead conduit after underground power installed

Tags: electrical

The power company has installed underground power, so theyll be removing the lines from the roof weatherhead & conduit. How can we cap the conduit to prevent incects & small animals from getting in afterwards. Not sure the power company will do well, so want some options that will be sturdy and permanent

Comment: For a better answer, try posting a picture.

Answer (score 5):

If it's threaded metal, as is typical for a mast, **don't** cut it. Then you'd have no threads, which is inconvenient.

Remove the weatherhead fitting and screw on a cap. Assuming you're not going to just remove the whole thing and patch the holes in the building, at this time, based on your question.

If you are leaving it in place, you also want to plug the bottom end with duct seal, (gray putty from the electrical aisle, typically sold in one-pound blocks) or it will tend to condense moisture out of the air freely moving into it that will drip down. By plugging the bottom with duct seal air movement and condensation resulting are greatly reduced.

Answer (score 2):

Ecnerwal's right, but if you want to cut it to make it shorter and less of an eyesore, just use a [rubber test cap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssn1h.png). It's unlikely that rodents will try to get through something in that position. You could stuff the conduit full of wire mesh as a fallback.

Really, though, I'd be detaching the mast or cutting it below the roof line and repairing the roof. If you have an extra shingle or two (or can procure a match), that's fairly trivial DIY work.